# Como pegar última palavra de uma string em PHP?

Tags: php, string

Por exemplo: "JOÃO FULANO DE TAL".
Desejo pegar somente a palavra "TAL".

Comment: Aconteceu alguma coisa pra trocar a aceitação? Você fez todos os testes necessários e viu que a que você aceitou agora tem problemas em algumas situações? O próprio exemplo postado não funciona. Mas olha só o resultado: https://ideone.com/Ka7p7f

Comment: não entendo uma pergunta boa e genuína como esta ser negativada, não entendo por que há respostas a pergunta com boa pontuação e a pergunta não, é como se aqui as pessoas não se importasse com quem tem dúvidas só com quem tem o conhecimento.

Comment: A unica coisa que não entendi foi que quem fechou também respondeu a pergunta. Vai entender...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Usando a função `strrchr()`**  [**veja no ideone**](https://ideone.com/VgIqN8)

```
$string ="Eu não recomendaria o uso de expressões regulares, pois é desnecessário, a menos que você realmente queira, por algum motivo";

$ultima_palavra = strrchr($string,' ');

echo $ultima_palavra;
```

**strrchr()** - retorna a parte que inicia na última ocorrência

**Outra forma:**

```
$string = 'JOÃO FULANO DE TAL';
$partes = explode(' ', $string);
$ultima_palavra = array_pop($partes);

echo $ultima_palavra;
```

O `explode()` separa uma string em um array de várias strings menores com base em um caractere divisor, que pode ser um ponto, uma vírgula ou qualquer outro caractere ou string (no seu caso um espaço). Sua sintaxe é assim:

```
explode( separador,string,limite )
```

- `separador`: O caractere que deve ser encontrado dentro da string para dividir a mesma;
- `string`: O texto no qual queremos fazer a divisão;
- `limite`: É a quantidade de vezes que o comando deve repartir a string. Este parâmetro e opcional e se não informado a divisão se dará por toda string.

  `array_pop()` extrai e retorna o último elemento do array

Answer (score 8):

A forma mais simples e um pouco ingênua seria isto (não garanto que atende qualquer situação, mas pergunta não diz muito:

```
$palavras = explode(' ', 'José da Silva');
echo $palavras[count($palavras) - 1];
```

Você usa uma função que já quebra as palavras baseado no espaço gerando um *array*, aí é só pegar o último elemento dele.

De acordo com o bfavaretto abaixo pode fazer um pouco melhor e assim de forma um pouco menos ingênua:

```
$texto = 'José da Silva';
$texto = trim($texto);
echo substr($texto, strrpos($texto, ' ') + 1);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5UHqEn). E [no **rep.it**](https://repl.it/join/xstfgcih-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/LastWord.php).

- [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
- [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

Comment: "Simples" depende do ponto de vista. Acho isto mais simples, e imagino até que você concorde: `substr($texto, strrpos($texto, ' '))`.

Comment: Concordo sim, nem lembrava do tal do `strrpos()` :) Mas seria ingênua também.

Comment: Ingênuo foi eu ter errado o índice de início por `1` :D. Precisaria ser `strrpos($texto, ' ')+1` pra não pegar o próprio espaço.

Comment: @bfavaretto é verdade, errei por culpa sua :P Agora está ok. Estava pensando em fazer teste de performance, mas eu já tenho ideia, e não vale o esforço.

Comment: strrpos é a melhor opção. Não tem porque complicar explodindo o espaço.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar **[preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)** com uma expressão regular:

```
preg_match("|\w+?$|", $string, $ultima);
```

Irá pegar sempre os últimos caracteres<sup>**1**</sup> do final do texto pra trás (`$`) até o que não for *alfanumérico* ou *underscore* (`\w`), no caso, o *espaço* antes de "TAL".

```
<?
$string = "JOÃO FULANO DE TAL";
preg_match("|\w+?$|", $string, $ultima);
echo $ultima[0]; // imprime: TAL
?>
```

> **<sup>1</sup>** Só vai funcionar com palavras sem caracteres especiais.

Answer (score 2):

Complementado as respostas já dadas; existem alguns meios de se fazer, nenhum devidamente "certo". O que pode ser feito é isolar e deixar o mais *clean* possível o código.

O primeiro exemplo seria utilizar RegEx:

```
$string = "mauro é perfeito";

preg_match("/[\w\-]+$/", $string, $matches);

echo $matches[0]; //perfeito
```

Mas como nada é perfeito (nem eu), utilizar `regex` não é o caminho mais simplório, mas em relação ao `explode()` ele fica "na frente" em quesito `XGH`.

O segundo caminho, utilizando o `explode()` seria usar o método `end()` para obter a última ocorrência.

```
$string = "mauro é perfeito";
$string = explode(" ", $string );

$last_word = end($string);

echo $last_word; //perfeito
```

Comment: A função end só funciona em variáveis, pois ela pede um argumento por referência. Isso aí vai gerar um erro em algumas versões do PHP

Comment: Gera um notice, mas como é para fins didáticos, não vejo problema.

Comment: Bem, o `E_NOTICE` indica que algo está errado. Acho que é válido você simplesmente adicionar o resultado de `explode` na variável. Entenda como crítica construtiva: Se o exemplo é didático, ele tem que ser certo.